# Can't delete multiple files with spaces on name with rm

Tags: bash, arch-linux, rm, dash

I'm working on a deploy script for my dotfiles, they are stored on a Git bare repository, from which i `git checkout` it's files into my home directory, in order to seamlessy do it without thousands of Git checkout errors, i must remove the already existing ones (`.bashrc` for instance), i'm actually retrieving them with the following command

```bsh
git --git-dir=$HOME/repos/dots --work-tree=$HOME ls-tree --full-tree --full-name --name-only -r HEAD | sed "s|^|/mnt/home/henriquehbr/|"
```

> Note: the reason for `/mnt` is that it is the mountpoint for my chrooted installation, i'm actually running it from my custom Arch Linux installation image

But when it comes to actually removing these files, i had no success, the problem lies on the ones that contains spaces in their names (`Font\ Awesome\ Icons.otf` for instance)

I've tried quoting every single file to be removed by piping the command above on the following sequence of commands:

```bsh
<get_dotfiles> | sed "s|^|\"/mnt/home/henriquehbr/|" | sed "s/$/\"/"
```

The method above didn't worked, i think `rm` was treating the quotes literally, as if they were part of the filename

Other trial was by making a good ol' `for` loop:

```bsh
dotfiles=$(git --git-dir=$HOME/repos/dots --work-tree=$HOME ls-tree --full-tree --full-name --name-only -r HEAD | sed "s|^|/mnt/home/henriquehbr/|")

for dotfile in $dotfiles; do
    echo "$dotfile" # Works properly, displays dotfile path
    rm "$dotfile" # Doesn't works, writes: '$'\n'' after the path and fails
done
```

Comment: If you are not depending on substituting variables, it's always safer to single quote strings (`'string or regexp'`) rather than double quote (`"string or regexp"`). Single quotes prevent shell interpretation. Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @ibuprofen Both samples weren't intended for showing the `rm` usage, the first one is just for showing the command i'm using to fetch dotfiles, the second command surround each one of them in double quotes, the actual code is the third sample

Comment: @waltinator I'm using shellcheck for linting my script, but it didn't complained about anything wrong

Comment: @ibuprofen sorry, my mistake, forgot to add it from my code, already edited the question, even with the forward slash, it doesn't works, nothing is removed

Comment: OK. That out of the way. But, hmm: I do not get how your `echo` statements yield the result you want. `dotfiles` is not an array. You miss end quote. etc. And: yes. Even if shellcheck does not say anything about double-quoted patterns in `sed`, waltinator is completely right.

Comment: Your echo statements looks like they would end up with something like `"/mnt/home/henriquehbr/Font` next line `Awesome` next line `Icons.otf` next line `"/mnt/home/henriquehbr/` ...

Comment: Yes, that was happening, the paths were being splitted like that, but i've gave up of this method and adhered the one i posted as an answer

Comment: But your Q say: `echo "$dotfile" # Works properly, displays dotfile path`

Comment: This was happening on the `rm`command, not on the `echo`, there were some weird `'$'\n''` separator between each path, but anyways, this was already solved, thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure. Was only trying to figure out what was happening before attacking the real issue :P, From what you say it sounds like you have modified `IFS`. Something like `IFS=""`. In that case what you see is not `echo` printing file by file, - but the entire list of files in one string. When you do `rm`  the `'$'\n''` is `rm` displaying the string with newlines escaped. It should get more clear if you do: `echo "FILE: $dotfile"`. (As in explain what was happening with your script - as I guess that would be of interest as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up with a way simpler solution that doesn't require all this complexity, a simple "forced" git checkout does the trick of replacing all my old dotfiles on the deploy process:

```
git checkout -f
```

> Props to [Sir_not_sir](https://www.reddit.com/user/Sir_not_sir/) on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/nyb0ph/rm_cant_delete_multiple_files_with_spaces_on_name/h1j5tp6?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 5):

Use null bytes as separators:

```
git ls-tree -z … | xargs -0 rm
```

Note that in most shells, you can't put null bytes in a variable, so `$(git ls-tree -z …)` won't do anything useful.

Your attempts with quotes couldn't have worked if they resulted in passing the quotes to `rm`. `rm`, like most programs, just expects file names. To it, `"` is an ordinary character, like any other character that can appear in a file name. Injecting quotes also cannot help with substitution in the shell: an unquoted variable substitution or command substitution (`$foo` or `$(mycommand …)`) just splits at whitespace (and then treats each word as a wildcard pattern), quotes are not relevant at this stage. Injecting quotes and passing to `xargs` (without `-0`) can work if the filenames themselves don't contain characters that are too “exotic”, such as backslashes, tabs, double quotes, etc. but it's far more complicated than using `git ls-tree -z` and `xargs -0`.

Assuming that the file names don't contain any of the characters that `git ls-tree` itself quotes (which includes newlines), this will work (once again, without meddling with quotes):

```
set -f # disable wildcard expansion (globbing)
IFS='
' # set only newline as the word separator
for dotfile in $(git ls-tree …); do …
```

Not that any of this is a good idea. If you just want to forcibly erase the existing files when you run `git checkout`, Git will happily remove files if you run `git checkout -f …`. It would be safer to check the existing files in, in case they turned out to contain something important.

```
git checkout -b original-files
git --git-dir=… ls-tree -z | xargs -0 git add
git commit -m "Original files on $HOSTNAME"
git checkout origin/master
```